# Black line on top of video Bootstrap CSS HTML5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video

I am trying to create a website with bootstrap css. I want to put a video on the top of the website that runs continuously. The problem is that there is a black bar on top of the video no matter how I style it. The dimensions of the video are 640x480.

Below is my code. Thanks for the help!

```css
.video-container { 
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    width:100% !important;

    height:auto !important;
    /*background-color:grey;
    opacity:0.6;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-container" >
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" id="video" style="width:100%; height:auto !important;" poster="pics/movie_poster.jpg">
        <source src="mov/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="mov/movie.mebm" type="video/webm">   
        <source src="mov/movie.ogv" type="video/ogg">   
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at this very helpful article http://zerosixthree.se/create-a-responsive-header-video-with-graceful-degradation/    Also i would stay away from using `!important`

Comment: Is the black bar on top of the video when the video is playing? Also, what version of Bootstrap are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks a lot for the support. The problem was in the video itself. The black bars were added when I converted the video in the different formats. I edited the video directly with Adobe Premiere which solved the problem.